# Drawing line between 2+ markers/wievpoints (not dynamically) in a MapBox on Android

Tags: java, android, navigation, mapbox, mapbox-android

dev spirits :)

Since yesterday I'm diggning through the google and github to find an answer to the  above question. I cannot find correct solution on mapbox documentation page as well.

Comment: Lines can be drawn either with a LineLayer (low level but flexible api with many configurations) or a PolyLine (high level but configurations are limited)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found the solution! Beside the `PolyLine` there have to be `Markers` placed on the map as well. Nevertheless, if we would like to use all the markers that represents waypoint it will be to crowded, so only the origin and destination markers will be enough. Also, lats and lngs for markers have to be taken from the Array (Don't know why, but the line is not visible if we use ArrayList).

```java
positions = PolylineUtils.decode(attraction.getWaypoints(),5);
latLng = new LatLng[positions.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < positions.size(); i++) {
    latLng[i] = new LatLng(
            positions.get(i).latitude(),
            positions.get(i).longitude());
}


mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().setPosition(new LatLng(latLng[0].getLatitude(),latLng[0].getLongitude())));
mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().setPosition(new LatLng(latLng[latLng.length-1].getLatitude(),latLng[latLng.length-1].getLongitude())));


// Draw Points on MapView
mapboxMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
        .add(latLng)
        .color(Color.parseColor("#38afea"))
        .width(5));
```